# Not able to retrieve session values Back

Tags: asp.net

Pls Help me, In my application I am storing some values in session. When I host the application in the **server** and store the session values in a page and  redirect to another site and returning back to the domain I am unable to retrive the session values, but If I do the same in **local host server**, I am getting all the session values back, can anybody explain me the reason...????  I have set session mode as Inproc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET session (by default) is cookie based - so you need to check two things:

1. If session cookie with original request is being send with the next request to your domain (this will need domain name to be same for both requests)
2. Whether session is getting timed out at server end

Comment: Thank U it was because of time out set